# How can I detect when my laptop is going to sleep

Tags: files, fedora, suspend, d-bus

I'm using fedora 28. I have a series of programs that I'm launching based off lock and unlock times, but I wanted these programs to adjust their behavior if sleep is detected.

So I want to create flag files (empty files whose existence dictates action) whenever my laptop goes to sleep, but I'm unsure of how to actually detect sleep. If I was more comfortable with D-Bus I would just monitor for it, but I still don't get how it actually works.

what is an effective way to monitor for suspend or wake from sleep actions?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/683701/how-to-hook-to-monitor-sleep-event

Comment: see `man systemd-suspend.service` and create a Unit fot it.